# Adding Modernizr to js project

Tags: npm, build, gulp, modernizr

I have a project (Gulp) which I need to add a custom modernizr build, it's just a few rules.

At the moment I have pasted the big lump of the build code at the top of my main.js but would like a more elegant solution.

I tried an external module with import but I could not trigger the test. Ideally using npm and just choosing the tests I need would be ideal.

I have looked at the docs but just can't seem to get it working. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got mine to work by adding the modernizr dependency in my package.json and then writing all the necessary build code in the modernizr-config.json. I then compile modernizr-config.json as a post install script.

`"postinstall": "modernizr -c modernizr-config.json"`

The Modernizr documentation helps with the build : https://modernizr.com/docs